# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database with SQLAlchemy. I've installed psycopg2. However, I get the error `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres`. How do I configure SQLAlchemy to connect to PostgreSQL?

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgres://username@localhost:5432/template1"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 427):

The URI should start with `postgresql://` instead of `postgres://`. SQLAlchemy used to accept both, but has removed support for the `postgres` name.

Comment: "but has removed support for the postgres name" Do you know when?

Comment: How many thousands of apps did they break for no reason? Ridiculous. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle

Comment: "postgres" was deprecated in 2009, and SQLAlchemy had emitted deprecation warnings from v0.6 to v1.3.  It was finally removed in v1.4 in 2021.  See https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6083#issuecomment-801478013

There was over 10 years of support for a deprecated command.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! My URL was starting from `postgressql`.

Answer (score 146):

SQLAlchemy 1.4 removed the deprecated `postgres` dialect name, the name `postgresql` must be used instead now. The dialect is the part before the `://` in the URL. SQLAlchemy 1.3 and earlier showed a deprecation warning but still accepted it.

To fix this, rename `postgres://` in the URL to `postgresql://`.

This error currently shows up when working with Heroku, which uses `postgres` in the `DATABASE_URL` they provide, which you probably use for `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`. To work around this until they update it, update the variable in the Heroku dashboard to use `postgresql`.

Comment: if by variables you mean config variables, I tried doing so & keep on getting `Item could not be updated: Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL`

Comment: @Daniyaldehleh I cannot really tell what the real issue is because you do not give me enough information about what exactly you did. Kindly let me know what exactly you tried and I may help

Comment: @Daniyaldehleh I worked around with a simple replace method in your Python script, and not in Heroku dashboard, since that won't work, as you mentioned. So you could do: `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL?sslmode=require').replace('postgres://', 'postgresql://')`.

Comment: Thanks guys! i actually ended up contacting heroku & they gave me this doc which solved the problem (https://help.heroku.com/ZKNTJQSK/why-is-sqlalchemy-1-4-x-not-connecting-to-heroku-postgres). Code: `uri = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")  # or other relevant config var
if uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)`

Comment: After adding the code above and trying to run app.py, the follow error is outputed:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Do they make changes like this just to annoy us?

Comment: This answer is still applicable today. You'll also find that you cannot simply edit the Config Vars in your Heroku dashboard with the `postgresql://` change to the URL (which would be more secure) so I had to hard code the URL.

Comment: @Stonecraft "postgres" has never been a valid dialect and has been deprecated for 11 years before being removed from SQLAlchemy. In other words, you have had 11 years of warnings telling you to stop using it and switch to "postgresql". If you’re still annoyed by that, then don’t use SQLAlchemy 1.4.

Answer (score 29):

The problem in heroku have been resolved by using simple python url replace code

```
import os
import re

uri = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")  # or other relevant config var
if uri and uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)
# rest of connection code using the connection string `uri`
```

source : https://help.heroku.com/ZKNTJQSK/why-is-sqlalchemy-1-4-x-not-connecting-to-heroku-postgres

Answer (score 10):

To fix this, rename `postgres://` in the URL to `postgresql+psycopg2://`.

Comment: Converting the dialect name from postgres to postgresql is covered by the existing answers.  Specifying the driver does no harm, but it isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: I've got this error ''sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql'' when i was dealing with the existing solution but when i try to specify the driver as recommend here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2, i resolved the issue

Comment: psycopg2 is SQLAlchemy's [default driver](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#postgresql) for Postgresql; `create_engine('postgresql://...)` will use it automatically if it's installed and no driver is specified.  Perhaps there was a typo in your code and rewriting the statement fixed it.

Comment: This answer resolved my issue. I'm using PyCharm with sqlalchemy/postgresql.

Comment: this one worked for me , i'm using alembic with sqlalchemy inside an alpine docker container

Answer (score 4):

All recipies I found tell the same "use postresql instead of postgres". But it does't work for me since my DB prefix is already ok "postresql".

After some survey I managed to find the problem. The thing is "alembic.ini" contains general template for db url `sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname`
Use `sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://user:pass@localhost/dbname` instead. It works.

Answer (score 2):

```
# production or dev DB
try:
    prodURI = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
    prodURI = prodURI.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = prodURI

except:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///MYDATABASE'
```

I tried all the above answers, but only this worked for me. I followed [Heroku's official suggestion](https://help.heroku.com/ZKNTJQSK/why-is-sqlalchemy-1-4-x-not-connecting-to-heroku-postgres) (mentioned in previous comments), but no luck. I think taking off the 1 at the end of `replace()` may have helped.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Kaitlin Berryman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19223690/kaitlin-berryman) said the Heroku official answer is not working, to avoid putting your DB credentials add this before `db.create_all()`:

```py
# create the database and the db table
import os
import re

uri = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
# or other relevant config var
if uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = uri
```

Answer (score -2):

after reading @gitau-harrison answer and knowing that it is a **SQLAlchemy** issue, instead of updating the variable in the Heroku dashboard to use postgresql, I changed the **version of SQLAlchemy** in 'requirements.txt' to 1.3.7 (was 1.4.18) and this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: ...but now you're using an old version of SQLAlchemy. Wouldn't it be better to use a current versoin?