# Flask and Heroku sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

When I run

```
heroku run python
>>> from app.main import app
>>> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
'postgres://<url string>' # the database url is passed correctly
>>> from app.main import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

it gives this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1039, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1031, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 556, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = self._sa.create_engine(sa_url, options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 972, in create_engine
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 520, in create_engine
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 653, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 342, in load
    "Can't load plugin: %s:%s" % (self.group, name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres
```

I'm confused because I'm new to Heroku and Postgresql (been using SQLite until now) and none of the tutorials I'm following explain how it all connects to Flask, only how to do it. So I don't understand what to look at to fix the problem. Is there any other code I should include in the question?

(Most of the other questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62688256/10753968) are typos or errors that don't fix this issue.)

Comment: Could you add your code, or at least a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is due to a change in the sqlalchemy library.  It was an announced deprecation in the changing of the dialect (the part before the ':' in the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI) name `postgres` to `postgresql`.  They released this breaking change from this [github commit](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/a9b068ae564e5e775e312373088545b75aeaa1b0) with a [minor version release](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-3687655465c25a39b968b4f5f6e9170b), which is in their policy to do so.

Heroku's default dialect is `postgres` in the DATABASE_URL they provide, which gets translated into the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI.  Heroku could update their postgres add-on if updating does not break other libraries which might depend on it.

In the meantime, you can pin your sqlalchemy library back to <1.4.0 (1.3.23 is the last 1.3.x release), and it should work.

Alternatively, you can update your code to modify the dialect.

Answer (score 21):

Here's a quick one that works for me, with the latest PostgreSQL on Heroku:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL').replace("://", "ql://", 1)
```

Just hacks the `postgres://` from Heroku (which can't be edited) to `postgresql://`.

Comment: It might be worth doing a full:

```python
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL').replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)
```

so that this continues to work if Heroku updates the value of the environment variable

Answer (score -1):

I was pushing my fast API with the SQLAlchemy ORM project to Heroku using PostgreSQL+asyncpg and also stumbled on this problem, I fixed it using the following:

```py
def change_postgres_connection_string(connection_string):
    if connection_string.startswith('postgresql+asyncpg://'):
        return connection_string
    parts = connection_string.split(':')
    parts[0] = 'postgresql+asyncpg'
    return ':'.join(parts)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76280893/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: downvoted because really it has 0 explanation where and how this piece of code is used.