# Doccano: unable to upload a jsonl

Tags: doccano

I tried to upload a jsonl file for sequence labelling task and have the following in the console:

```
POST https://website.azurewebsites.net/v1/projects/16/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at t.exports
    at t.exports
    at XMLHttpRequest._.onreadystatechange
```

What can I do ?

Comment: 500 is a serverside error.

Comment: Thank you, it was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688256/sqlalchemy-exc-nosuchmoduleerror-cant-load-plugin-sqlalchemy-dialectspostgre