# Heroku database showing password authentication failed after maintenance

Tags: database, postgresql, flask, heroku, heroku-postgres

So i received a message from heroku saying it needs to carry out maintenance on my database and will be read only for a bit. However I go to check my site and the site isn't working for the pages that require data from the database, I go to check the logs and see this error message:

```
2022-05-20T09:57:55.246102+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (52.18.116.67), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "MYUSERNAME"
2022-05-20T09:57:55.246102+00:00 app[web.1]: connection to server at ".eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (52.18.116.67), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP", user "MYUSERNAME", database "DATABASE", no encryption
```

I haven't touched or changed anything, so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Are you hard coding the database url in you app or getting it from environment variable?

Comment: @ahmed getting the url like this uri = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_URI_PROD') which gets the environment variable from heroku secret keys

Comment: It should be `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: @ahmed ive always had it as that and its worked, inst database URL something different?

Comment: Heroku can change the url, you can even change it from dashboard, that's why you have to use `DATABASE_URL` which heroku ensure it will always have a working url

Comment: @ahmed try this now i get another error sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen if you are not using the "dynamic" environment variable that Heroku manage for connecting to a PostgreSQL database

If you have just one, it's better to use DATABASE_URL as it always have up-to-date location and credentials

Heroku can change the url for various reasons, ex credentials rotation

If you are using sqlalchemy you might need a slight [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64698899/3896300):

```
os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL').replace('postgres://', 'postgresql://')
```